# How to stop elements from wrapping when I zoom page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have been working on a website. The problem is when I change the resolution of the page with the browser(CTRL -/ + OR CTRL ZOOM), the last button overflows to downwards. I tried overflow:hidden but I couldn't solve it.
And also I realized that in some computer, depending on the resolution the button overflow to downwards also even though I don't zoom it.

**Without Zoom**
[image: enter image descrifdf]

**With Zoom**
[image]

Comment: This is not "overflow" in CSS terms, which is why you find that `overflow: hidden` doesn't work. Anyway, we have to see the HTML/CSS you're using, otherwise we can't give you a definitive solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the element that contains the menu items.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! ...but, next time, if you could show your HTML and CSS it's *easier* to help...

Answer (score 0):

if you explicitly define the width of the container it will not shrink and the elements will not wrap.